# Kivy Launcher does not launch scripts

Tags: python, kivy

I am testing my kivy knowledge. In my script I use canvas, label and mouse.
My python(kivy) script is running in environment of pyscripter. When I use kivy launcher, program falls down during loading. I compared my script with kivy examples I did not found source of my problem. Please, explain to me problem.
Thank You.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from enum import Enum
import collections

Palete = collections.namedtuple('Palete',
                                       ['Pos', 'Fig', 'Select'])
pal = Palete((1,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,0,1))





class TypPos(Enum):
    FIGURE   = 1
    POSITION = 2

    FICT     = 10

class Status(Enum):
    QUIET   = 1
    SELECT  = 2
    JUMP    = 3

class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i =0
        self.j =0
        self.x =0
        self.y =0
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.cont = None

    def SetIJ(self, i, j):
        self.i =i
        self.j =j

    def SetXY(self, x, y):
        self.x =x
        self.y =y

    def SetCont(self, cont):
        self.cont = cont

    def SetColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def GetColorXY(self):
        return self.x, self.y, self.color

    def GetIJ(self):
        return self.i, self.j

class Board:
    def __init__(self,size,radius, offsetX, offsetY):
        self.size = size
        self.count  = 9*size * size
        self.dist = 2 * radius + radius * 0.5
        self.radius = radius

        self.liPlan = []
        self.ind = 0
        self.offsetX = offsetX
        self.offsetY = offsetY
        self.PrepareBoard()
        self.status = Status.QUIET
        self.select = 0
        self.countfig = size*size*5-1

    def PrepareBoard(self):
        for i in range(0,self.size):
            for j in range(0, 3*self.size):
                pos = Position()
                if j>=self.size and j<2*self.size:
                    cont = TypPos.FIGURE
                else:
                    cont = TypPos.FICT

                pos.SetIJ(i, j)
                pos.SetCont(cont)
                self.liPlan.append(pos)

        for i in range(self.size, 2*self.size):
            for j in range(0, 3*self.size):
                    pos = Position()
                    cont = TypPos.FIGURE
                    pos.SetIJ(i, j)
                    pos.SetCont(cont)
                    self.liPlan.append(pos)

        for i in range(2*self.size, 3*self.size):
            for j in range(0, 3*self.size):
                pos = Position()
                if j>=self.size and j<2*self.size:
                    cont = TypPos.FIGURE
                else:
                    cont = TypPos.FICT
                pos.SetIJ(i, j)
                pos.SetCont(cont)
                self.liPlan.append(pos)

        self.liPlan[self.size].SetCont(TypPos.POSITION)

        return

    def GetRGB(self, col):
        if col == TypPos.FIGURE:
            rgb = pal.Fig
        elif col == TypPos.POSITION:
            rgb = pal.Pos
        else:
            rgb = None

        return rgb


    def XYFromInd(self,ind):
        print(str(ind))
        pos = self.liPlan[ind]

        if pos.cont == TypPos.FICT:
 #          rgb = (0, 1, 0)
           pos.SetXY(0,0)
           pos.SetColor(None)
           return

        else:
            rgb = self.GetRGB(pos.cont)

        red = ind+1
        i = red//(3*self.size)
        j =red%(3*self.size)
        if j==0:
            i = i-1
            j = 3 *self.size-1
        else:
            j = j-1

        y =  self.dist*3*self.size - (i+1) * self.dist + self.offsetY
        x =  (j+1)* self.dist + self.offsetX

        self.liPlan[ind].SetXY(x,y)
        self.liPlan[ind].SetColor(rgb)
        return

    def IndFromXY(self, x, y):
        x= x - self.offsetX - self.dist/2
        y= -(y - self.offsetY - self.dist*3*self.size) + self.dist/2

        ii = x/self.dist
        jj = y/self.dist

        i = int(round(ii))-1
        j = int(round(jj))-1

        if j < 0:
            j = 0

        ind = j* self.size*3 + i
        return ind

    def CoordinatePos(self):
#        for i in range(0,self.count):
        for i in range(0,len(self.liPlan)):
            self.XYFromInd(i)
        return

    def SelectTask(self, x, y):
        ind = self.IndFromXY(x, y)
        pos = self.liPlan[ind]
        x, y, rgb = pos.GetColorXY()


        if self.status == Status.QUIET:
            if pos.cont ==TypPos.FIGURE:
                color = self.MarkFig(ind)
                self.liPlan[ind].SetColor(color)
                return
            else:
                return

        if self.status == Status.SELECT:
            if ind == self.select:
                self.UnMarkFig(ind)
                return

            if self.liPlan[ind].cont ==TypPos.POSITION:
                self.Jump(ind)
                return
        return

    def MarkFig(self, ind):
        col = pal.Select
        self.status = Status.SELECT
        self.select = ind
        return col

    def UnMarkFig(self, ind):
        self.status = Status.QUIET
        self.liPlan[ind].cont = TypPos.FIGURE
        self.liPlan[ind].SetColor(pal.Fig)
        return

    def Jump(self,ind):
        out = self.IndexOut(ind, self.select)

        if self.liPlan[out].cont == TypPos.POSITION:
            return

        self.status= Status.QUIET

        self.liPlan[ind].cont = TypPos.FIGURE
        self.liPlan[ind].SetColor(pal.Fig)

        self.liPlan[self.select].cont = TypPos.POSITION
        self.liPlan[self.select].SetColor(pal.Pos)

        self.liPlan[out].cont = TypPos.POSITION
        self.liPlan[out].SetColor(pal.Pos)

        self.countfig = self.countfig-1
        return

    def IndexOut(self, ind, select):
        i1, j1 = self.liPlan[ind].GetIJ()
        i2, j2 = self.liPlan[select].GetIJ()
        i = (i1 + i2)//2
        j = (j1 + j2)//2
        out = i*self.size*3 + j
        return out


class CustomLayout(Widget):

    def __init__(self, label, wid, **kwargs):

        super(CustomLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.board = Board(5, 10, 30, 40)
        self.wid = wid
        label.text = 'Count: ' + str(self.board.countfig)
        self.label = label


        self.board.CoordinatePos()

        for i in range(0,self.board.count):
            pos = self.board.liPlan[i]
            x, y, rgb = pos.GetColorXY()
            if rgb == None:
                continue

            with self.canvas:
                Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])
                size1=(self.board.radius*2, self.board.radius*2)
                pos1 = (x, y)
                Ellipse(size= size1, pos=pos1)
        return


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.count = self.board.countfig
        self.board.SelectTask(touch.x, touch.y)
        self.label.text = 'Count: ' + str(self.board.countfig)

        for i in range(0,self.board.count):
            pos = self.board.liPlan[i]
            x, y, rgb = pos.GetColorXY()
            if rgb == None:
                continue

            with self.canvas:
                Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2])
                size1=(self.board.radius*2, self.board.radius*2)
                pos1 = (x, y)
                Ellipse(size= size1, pos=pos1)

class JumperApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()

        label = Label(pos=(60, 50))
        paint = CustomLayout(label, parent)


        parent.add_widget(label)
        parent.add_widget(paint)


        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    JumperApp().run()
```

android.text:

```
title=JumperApp.py
author=Black
orientation=landscape
```

Comment: Have any error messages?

Comment: have you tried to run kivy examples with the launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, use [adb logcat](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform) to debug.

In this case, the launcher probably doesn't have the enum module.

Comment: Thank You. I removed enum module and Kivy's loading is without problems.

Comment: @inclement Is there any way to install modules on such a launcher? I am using the kivy launcher too and I believe some of the modules I used to run the code on my PC might be causing this issue.

Comment: @inclement Never mind, I found this on another thread: The Kivy Launcher is fine for testing simple applications, but in order to deploy an app on the app store, or to develop an app with more than the basic dependencies, you will need to compile it into an APK. Also, it's possible to retrieve a debug report from an APK, which may not be possible with the Kivy Launcher.